# Embedding MS query into an excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have made an excel workbook consisting of several complex worksheets.

Now I have created queries using MS query to allow me to gather the information needed for calculations from these different worksheets. Everything works just fine until I move the workbook to a new location.

As this is going to happen often and I do not want to rebuild my queries every time I was wondering if there is a way to link my query to the workbook itself and not to a specific file location.

Can anybody help me?

This is de SQL build up of the query

```
SELECT `'Production Plan$'`.`Scheduled Operation`, `Tests$`.`Test Name`, `Tests$`.`Tests per batch`, `Tests$`.`Ops PER BATCH or PER YR:`, `Tests$`.`Total Locations (MULTIPLIER):`, `Tests$`.`Retest Rate`, `'Production Plan$'`.`Batches for 2015`, `'Production Plan$'`.`Batches for 2016`, `'Production Plan$'`.`Batches for 2017`, `'Production Plan$'`.`Batches for 2018`
FROM `C:\Users\UGent\Desktop\XXX\XXX\Models\new model SV 0106.xlsx`.`'Production Plan$'` `'Production Plan$'`, `C:\Users\UGent\Desktop\XXX\XXX\Models\new model SV 0106.xlsx`.`Tests$` `Tests$`
WHERE `'Production Plan$'`.`Scheduled Operation` = `Tests$`.`Scheduled Operation:`
```

And this is the connection string

```
DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Users\UGent\Desktop\BQG\Genzyme\Models\new model SV 0106.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Users\UGent\Desktop\BQG\Genzyme\Models;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to link my query to the workbook
>   itself and not to a specific file location

**No** - you cannot "link` the query to an Excel Workbook as there is (as I am aware) no mechanism to track how you move the source Excel Workbook.

*What can you do?*

**Option 1 - Manual reconnection**

Write a VBA macro that will recreate the SQL query. It could work like this:

1. When opening your Workbook a VBA macro runs at the `Workbook.Open` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx)
2. The Event macro checks if the source worksheet is located in the correct file path. If not then (3)
3. If the file is not there then recreate then show a popup asking for the new file path. When the user clicks OK, recreate SQL query via VBA macro. You can use macro recording to extract the necessary VBA or see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819?wa=wsignin1.0).

Some example code of how to create a MS Query in VBA:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\test.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\;DriverId=1046;Ma" _
        ), Array("xBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")). _
        QueryTable
        .CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT `Sheet1$`.A, `Sheet1$`.B" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `C:\test.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Excel_Files"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

**Option 2 - Push the Excel to a network location**

Try locating the Workbook into a Network location that will not require frequently asking for the the source filepath. You can even place it as a link. It could work like this:

1. Download the file using VBA or tools on the `Data` ribbon section
2. Recreate the query as above

**Option 3 - Push the Excel source data to a database like SQL**

1. Push the data to SQL Server, MySQL or another easily accessible database
2. Make a permanent `SQL.OLEDB` connection from your master Workbook

Comment: Oke thank you.
Than I will have to start programming in VBA and that was something I was trying to avoid.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question - please mark my post as the answer to close this thread.

Comment: Could you give a quick idea on what the code would need to be? As I have no experience with vba.

Comment: Done. However, I would recommend you turn on `Record Macro` option when creating your connection manually. This will create your VBA code automatically. You can build on that.